# Don't work servlet. Issue with servlet mapping in web.xml

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

I have home page and when I click on reference Servlet don't work and I get error 404. I think issue in `web.xml` mapping, but a don't understand where. Please help me correct this issue. Thank you.

My `web.xml`

```
<!--Homepage.-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HomePageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ru.pravvich.servlets.HomePageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HomePageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!--Add user in database.-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AddUserServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ru.pravvich.servlets.AddUserServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddUserServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addition</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My jsp homepage:

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="addition.jsp">addition</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

And servlet with `doGet` method for it:

```
public class HomePageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp").forward(req,resp);
    }
}
```

And by `http://localhost:8080/items/` I get my home page.

But, when I click on reference from `index.jsp`, return: `HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]`

My `addition.jsp` same lie in `/WEB-INF/views/addition.jsp`

My Servlet for work with `addition.jsp` :

```
public class AddUserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private DBJoint db;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        db = (DBJoint) getServletContext().getAttribute("db");

        db.getDBExecutor().addUser(
            new User(req.getParameter("name"), 
                     req.getParameter("login"), 
                     req.getParameter("email")));

        req.setAttribute("serverAnswer", "Add ok!");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/answer.jsp").forward(req, resp);

    }
}
```

And `addition.jsp`:

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="addition">
        <input type="text" required placeholder="name" name="name"><br>
        <input type="text" required placeholder="login" name="login"><br>
        <input type="text" required placeholder="email" name="email"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="add">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use `try/catch` and debugger mode.

And try to use like this your `getRequestDispatcher`

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("answer.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

or

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("~/WEB-INF/views/answer.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

I think you need to get parameter for each of one, and than set. Try this;

```
public class AddUserServlet extends HttpServlet {

private DBJoint db;

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    db = (DBJoint) getServletContext().getAttribute("db");

    String Name = request.getParameter("name");
    String Login= request.getParameter("login");
    String Email= request.getParameter("email");

    db.getDBExecutor().addUser(
        new User(Name, Login, Email);

    //And you need to 'serverAnswer' item in your 'answer.jsp' you know.
    request.setAttribute("serverAnswer", "Add ok!");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("answer.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }    
}
```

And then you can use `getAttribute` like this in your `answer.jsp`,

`<%String Answer= (String)request.getAttribute("serverAnswer"); %><%= Answer%>`

Don't blame me, just i wanna help to you, i hope so it can be help to you, if you wanna you can look my trial project; `https://github.com/anymaa/GNOHesap`

Have a nice coding :)

Comment: Thank You. But I don't have a issue with data transfer between AddUserServlet and addition.jsp's  from. My issue : my reference `<li><a href="addition.jsp">addition</a></li>` get error 404. I can not access the page addition.jsp.

Comment: Did you try like this?

`<servlet-name>addition.jsp</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/addition.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>addition.jsp</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/addition</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
`

Comment: And i wanna ask you somethig, just ask :) Servlet Mapping in web.xml , is this neccessary? Cause i build a project and web.xml is empty, but i create each servlet, right click and add servlet, at the Deployment Descriptor include Server Mappings and i am seeing there my servlets, but i didn't add there manually. I am using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: I use IntelliJIDEA... How do this automatically with my IDE I don't know. I need use web.xml cause this is part of my quest. Earlier when all jsp files lie in wabapp all work. But I get task provide secure and move everything jsp to a folder WEB-INF. And mapping broke. Sorry but you mapping version from comment get same result(((